# Multiple Imputation on New/Predictor Data

Tags: r, missing-data

Can someone please help me understand how to handle missing values in new/unseen data?  I have investigated a handful of multiple imputation packages in R and all seem only to impute the training and test set (at the same time).  How do you then handle new unlabeled data to estimate in the same way that you did train/test?  Basically, I want to use multiple imputation for missing values in the training/test set and also the same model/method for predictor data.  Based on my research of multiple imputation (not an expert), it does not seem feasible to do this with MI?  However, for example, using caret, you can easily use the same model that was used in training/test for new data.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

** Edit

Basically, My data set contains many missing values.  Deletion is not an option as it will discard most of my train/test set.  Up to this point, I have encoded categorical variables, removed near zero variance and highl correlated variables.  After this preprocessing, I was able to easily apply the mice package for imputation

```
m=mice(sg.enc)
```

At this point, I could use the pool command to apply the model against the imputed data sets.  That works fine.  However, I know that future data will have missing values and would like to somehow apply this MI incrementally?

Comment: Can you show us what have you done so far (example)? Though in my opinion the best and only way of imputation is deletion ... especially when you dealing with empirical data sets.

Answer (score 0):

It does not have multiple imputation, but the yaImpute package has a predict() function to impute values for new data.  I ran a test using training data (that included NAs) to create a "yai" object, then used that object via predict() to impute values in a new testing data set.  Unlike Caret preProcess(), yaImpute supports factor variables (at least for imputing values for them) in its knn algorithm.  I did not yet test if factors can be part of the "predictors" for the missing target variables. yaImpute does support other imputation methods besides knn.